# Why do I get no output out of println in this case?

Tags: java, math, double, primes

I tried this a lot, and debugged it a few times, everything seems to be working and largest prime does indeed become the largest prime even if it takes rather long.

I can't get the printed value from `System.out.println`. I could find it through the debugger but the value is too high to find fast just holding down step over.

It compiles as well so I am stumped about what's the issue here. I would be very happy to know what I did wrong.

Edit: The reason why I wrote this code in the first place is because in the site project euler it asked for the largest prime value that when divided with the value of primer gave a whole number.

Is there a way at least that would allow me to make it faster with the same value? this seems rather impractical.

```
package unit5;

public class Primefinder { public static void main(String[] args)
{
double primer = 600851475143d;
double largestprime = 0;
Boolean ifprime = false;

for(double x = 2d; x < primer; x++)
{
    for(double z = 2d; z<x; z++)
    {
        if( (x%z == 0) && (z != x) )
        {
            ifprime = false;
            break;
        }
        else {
            ifprime = true;
        }

    }


    if((ifprime != false) && (x > largestprime))
    {
        largestprime = x;
    }

    ifprime = false;
}


System.out.print(largestprime);

}

}
```

Comment: why are you using `double` for something that will only hold integer values?

Comment: isn't the value of primer too high to be an integer value?

Comment: I mean integer values in the mathematical sense (any value without decimal places), not the Java/C family one (a number with 32 bits). Use long instead, it doesn't waste memory for storing the decimal point's location if you dont have one

Comment: Or use BigInteger, which is designed to deal with large integers.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the definition of the problem. As far as I can tell, the program is consistently calculating the largest prime that is less than primer.

Answer (score 0):

for other questions you might ask everywhere, please tell us that what is the purpose of your code. this way it is easier to get the fault.

the code you have written above runs completely but the numbers you have used are too big so you need to wait a lot, so that compiler be able to reach to this line:

```
System.out.print(largestprime);
```

use lower numbers (at least for test) or wait properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'primer' Value is very big.

So, loop is taking very much time to reach at '600851475143' value.

> Wait Sometime and it with show largest prime number